# Is data copied on the interop boundary?

Tags: c#, c++, interop

Suppose I have function written in C++ with a signature

```
extern "C" DLL_EXPORT bool __stdcall SendBytes(unsigned char* bytes, int size);
```

The DllImport declaration is as follows:

```
    [DllImport("MyDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
    public static extern bool SendBytes(byte[] bytes, int size);
```

If I do a call from C#

```
var bytesToSend = new byte[1000];
// Fill bytesToSend here
// ...
MyAPI.SendBytes(bytesToSend, 1000)
```

are bytesToSend copied on the boundary before entering in the C++ SendBytes function?

The same question applies to the situation when bytes are returned from the function.

*The byte type is blittable, but is it correct to receive a pointer to byte array as a pointer to unsigned char array in C++?*

**UPD:** According to the comment, strings are always copied when passed from managed memory to the unmanaged one. What is the best way to pass bytes then?

Comment: it is complicated. but well documented. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-strings

Comment: We can't see the [DllImport] declaration you used.  Tends to matter when the C++ code has no hope of doing this correctly, it doesn't know how many bytes are in the array.  But generally, no, a byte[] is a blittable type and the pinvoke marshaler only has to temporarily pin the array and pass a pointer to the first array element.